# Pre-filtering Microsoft Dynamic 365 SSRS not filtering base on opened record

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, ssrs-2008-r2, dynamics-365

I been dealing with a very unfriendly situation and cannot wrap my head around it. I applied same approach to another entity and it is working as expected but not sure why I cannot get it to work with this particular entity.

I am creating a report in SSRS and wanna make sure once an end user opens a record Pre-filtering applies to the opened record. (Record is Release of information (Roi for short))

in my SSRS I created added a SQL data source named "MSCRM_DataSource"

then I added my DataSet which is this:

-DataSets:

+Release_Of_Information

In my data set I have a simple code:

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3 
FROM FilteredReleaseOfInformation AS T1
WHERE ROIid = @SelectedForm
```

Then I added another DataSet and Named it as below:

+CRMAF_RoiID

above Data set has this code:

```
SELECT ROIid AS FormID
FROM FilteredReleaseOfInformation AS CRMAF_RoiID
```

Then I went for my parameters and first added one Parameter as follow.

**General Tab:**

Name: "CRMAF_RoiID"

Data Type: "Text"

Select Parameter Visibility: "internal"

**Default Values tab:**

Specify values:

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
<entity name="ReleaseOfInformation">
<attribute name="RoiID" /> 
</entity>
</fetch>
```

Lastly I added SelectedForm parameter as follows:

**General Tab**

Name: SelectedForm

Data type: Text

Parameter visibility: Hidden

**Available Values Tab**

Get values from a query

Dataset: CRMAF_RoiID

Value Field: FormID

Label Field: FormID

**Default Values Tab***

Get values from a query

DataSet: CRMAF_RoiID

Value field: FormID

When I go to my test environment, report runs, but picks the first GUID in the query and not the associated record that is opened therefore no matter what record is opened it shows the info of first person RoiID.

**PS: Report is in my solution

**PS: I checked and ROIid is searchable on the entity

Is there anything that comes to your mind that I am missing? I spent so long researching and yet couldn't get this form work.

I have another entity that is working fine I do not know why this one has issue.

Answer (score 0):

On your Dynamic-CRM check something and make sure the report is running on Current Record

[image]

if it is set on run for all related records Simply delete the report in your solution and add it again (preferably with a new name just add an _V2 or _V3 at the end of the name and set it up again.) this should do the trick as it did for me. I believe there is a bug in Dynamic CRM.